# Default class values and argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to write a class which can be initialized from either `argparse` object or the usual way. Here is my attempt:

```
class MyClass () :
    foo_default = 10

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs) :
        if len(args) > 0 :
            if len(kwargs) == 0 :
                kwargs, = args
            else : raise Exception("MyClass: cannot mix anonymous & named")
        # double defaulting because a missing command line arg results in a
        # present key but None value and the default is ignored
        self.foo = kwargs.get('foo', foo_default) or foo_default

    @staticmethod
    def add_arguments (parser) :
        parser.add_argument('-foo', type=int, help='for MyClass')
```

I intend to use it either like this: `MyClass(foo=42)` or like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
MyClass.add_arguments(parser)
args = parser.parse_args()
mc = MyClass(args.__dict__))
```

However, I get this error:

```
NameError: global name 'foo_default' is not defined
```

Why?

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Why not just subclass ArgumentParser and add in your logic in the new class? This is some convoluted code.

Comment: @SeanPerry: is it normal practice to subclass ArgumentParser?

Comment: If you mostly like a class but want to tweak behavior subclassing is perfectly acceptable. @sds, I do not understand your example well enough to offer an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo_default` is an attribute on `MyClass`, so you need to qualify:

```
self.foo = kwargs.get('foo', self.foo_default) or self.foo_default
```

Comment: isn't `foo_default` a _class_ attribute rather than an _instance_ one? shouldn't I be using `MyClass.foo_default`?

Comment: You could do either. self.foo_default would cover the case where you subclass MyClass and override its foo_default.